# Are firefox about:config entries saved somewhere besides prefs.js?

Tags: firefox, about-config

I played around with the about:config in firefox. I saved the prefs.js file beforehand in case something goes wrong. When I stop firefox now and replace the file with my earlier copy, the prefs in about:config do not change back to the original settings.

My questions are now: Are the "real" settings saved in another place and prefs.js is just used to load them? Why does replacing the prefs.js file not cause the settings to go back to the original?

Comment: They may have been stored in the `user.js` file. It's easy enough to see what file was last updated in the Firefox profile after making such a change.

Comment: thats what i thought too, but  my userprofile directory does not contain a file called user.js

Comment: See the latest-updated file. It might be in a subfolder.